# Why does Ubuntu create dublicates of a partition in /media?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I have a dual boot system with windows and ubuntu, each of them on a different partition. Additionally, i have a partition called `Multimedia` just for storing things like data files or my Eclipse Workspace. The path to this partition is `/media/user/Multimedia`. My problem is that for some reason ubuntu automatically has created several dublicates of this directory `/media/user/Multimedia2`,`/media/user/Multimedia3`,...

It gets really annoying because when a dublicate is created, it seems like ubuntu moves all the content to the newest copy of the folder and then eclipse cannot find the workspace anymore.

I'm quite new to linux and don't really understand this behaviour. Is this normal or can i prevent this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can't answer you completly why this happens. But I can tell you that you are not using the right folder for what you are doing. These folders are used by the systems automatically e.g. the /media/ folder is used for automatic mounts of CDROMs etc.
I would recommend you using only your /home/user/ for such things. E.g. create a /home/user/Multimedia that one won't be changed by the system automatically.

You could read up the Ubuntu structure here
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2037324

Comment: Thank you. I've chosen to put all the stuff on another "partition" because i wanted to use those files simultaneously on windows and ubuntu, e.g. pictures, music etc. But ok, maybe i could move at least the workspace into my home folder.